# Paypal Do direct Method

Tags: php, paypal

I am using the DoDirect method by PayPal.
A user made a transaction using that form. The transaction was done successfulky.
But unfortunately my query to insert the value into the database did not work. So there is no information regarding this transaction on my website.
When I see PayPal there is no way to contact the user because PayPal does not save the buyer's email id.
So I want to ask, can we save a buyer's email id on PayPal using the DoDirect method?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to make sure you included it in the DoDirectPayment request.  Can you provide a sample of the request you sent?

I am unable to reproduce what you're saying is happening in the sandbox.  Here is a sample request that I just sent.

```
[REQUESTDATA] => Array
    (
        [USER] => ***
        [PWD] => ***
        [VERSION] => 119.0
        [BUTTONSOURCE] => AngellEYE_PHPClass
        [SIGNATURE] => ***
        [METHOD] => DoDirectPayment
        [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
        [IPADDRESS] => 127.0.0.1
        [RETURNFMFDETAILS] => 1
        [CREDITCARDTYPE] => MasterCard
        [ACCT] => 5522340006063638
        [EXPDATE] => 022016
        [CVV2] => 456
        [EMAIL] => sandbox@domain.com
        [FIRSTNAME] => Tester
        [LASTNAME] => Testerson
        [STREET] => 707 W. Bay Drive
        [CITY] => Largo
        [STATE] => FL
        [COUNTRYCODE] => US
        [ZIP] => 33770
        [AMT] => 3.00
        [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
        [DESC] => Testing Payments Pro DESC Field
        [CUSTOM] => TEST
        [L_NAME0] => Test Widget
        [L_DESC0] => This is a test widget description.
        [L_AMT0] => 1.00
        [L_NUMBER0] => ABC-123
        [L_QTY0] => 1
        [L_NAME1] => Test Widget 2
        [L_DESC1] => This is a test widget description.
        [L_AMT1] => 2.00
        [L_NUMBER1] => ABC-XYZ
        [L_QTY1] => 1
    )
```

And then here's a copy of what I see when I run GetTransactionDetails for the transaction ID that I got back from that request, which does include the email address in the EMAIL parameter.

```
Array
(
    [RECEIVERBUSINESS] => sandbo_1215254764_biz@angelleye.com
    [RECEIVEREMAIL] => sandbo_1215254764_biz@angelleye.com
    [RECEIVERID] => ATSCG2QMC9KAU
    [EMAIL] => sandbox@domain.com
    [PAYERID] => WH8FUF8Q2TTU8
    [PAYERSTATUS] => unverified
    [COUNTRYCODE] => US
    [ADDRESSOWNER] => PayPal
    [ADDRESSSTATUS] => None
    [CUSTOM] => TEST
    [SALESTAX] => 0.00
    [SOFTDESCRIPTOR] => DREWANGELLS
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-12-22T09:03:28Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 3271f4646a9a0
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 119.0
    [BUILD] => 14077178
    [FIRSTNAME] => Tester
    [LASTNAME] => Testerson
    [TRANSACTIONID] => 54978042VY932040V
    [RECEIPTID] => 4345-6492-8319-3894
    [TRANSACTIONTYPE] => cart
    [PAYMENTTYPE] => instant
    [ORDERTIME] => 2014-12-22T09:01:25Z
    [AMT] => 3.00
    [FEEAMT] => 0.44
    [TAXAMT] => 0.00
    [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
    [HANDLINGAMT] => 0.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
    [PAYMENTSTATUS] => Completed
    [PENDINGREASON] => None
    [REASONCODE] => None
    [PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY] => Ineligible
    [PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE] => None
    [L_NAME0] => Test Widget
    [L_NAME1] => Test Widget 2
    [L_NUMBER0] => ABC-123
    [L_NUMBER1] => ABC-XYZ
    [L_QTY0] => 1
    [L_QTY1] => 1
    [L_TAXAMT0] => 0.00
    [L_TAXAMT1] => 0.00
    [L_SHIPPINGAMT0] => 0.00
    [L_SHIPPINGAMT1] => 0.00
    [L_HANDLINGAMT0] => 0.00
    [L_HANDLINGAMT1] => 0.00
    [L_CURRENCYCODE0] => USD
    [L_CURRENCYCODE1] => USD
    [L_TAXABLE0] => false
    [L_TAXABLE1] => false
    [L_AMT0] => 1.00
    [L_AMT1] => 2.00
)
```

Can you provide a similar sample set where the GetTransactionDetails response does not include the email address?

Comment: // Add request-specific fields to the request string.
 $nvpStr = "&PAYMENTACTION=$paymentType&AMT=$amount&CREDITCARDTYPE=$creditCardType&ACCT=$creditCardNumber".
 "&EXPDATE=$padDateMonth$expDateYear&CVV2=$cvv2Number&FIRSTNAME=".urlencode($from)."&LASTNAME=".urlencode($to).
 "&STREET=".urlencode($address1)."&CITY=".urlencode($city)."&STATE=".urlencode($state)."&ZIP=".urlencode($zip)."&COUNTRYCODE=$country&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID&CUSTOM=".urlencode($custom)."&EMAIL=$email";

Comment: It would be better to edit the question and add the sample there.  Also, I need to see the raw request that actually gets sent to PayPal. Not the code that generates the request.  So the end result for $nvpStr is what I'm wanting to see.

Comment: &PAYMENTACTION=Sale&AMT=25&CREDITCARDTYPE=visa&ACCT=4069929390343&EXPDATE=012020&CVV2=962&FIRSTNAME=Gurname&LASTNAME=Singh&STREET=India&CITY=Patiala&STATE=California&ZIP=12345&COUNTRYCODE=US&CURRENCYCODE=USD&CUSTOM=%09%09%09%09%09fvsdfsdf%09%09+++&EMAIL=gurnam@stelleninfotech.com

Comment: So you're saying you're sending that request but then the email address does not show up in the PayPal transaction details..??

Comment: yes its not showing up.I have put that on sandbox mode now and made transaction but didnot get that.